# how to call a function from another function - Node JS

Tags: node.js, express

I am still new to `Node Js`. Please  help me out.

I am calling a web service and based on its results I need to call another web service. The code is given below, however, I am not sure how to call the second web service (ex: `foo()`).

The 2nd method (That calls the 2nd web service) accepts 2 parameter:

1. Subject
2. Body

I need to call the web service `'https://somenew.com/v1/'`, and need to pass the following as headers as well :

```
`Content-Type : application/json`
```

Then As the body I need to pass the following properties :

```
  "name": "My name is alex",
  "gender": ["All"],
  "Subject":  "french",
  "Body":  "men",
  "arrayOfLikes": {"sf": "tennis"}
```

// 1st Method

```
app.post('/createthehospital/',function(req,res){
    var hos = req.body;
    Hos.create(hos, function(err,hos){
        if(err){
                         // Do nothing
        } else {

                foo('Subject', 'Body'); // CALLING NEW METHOD
            }
        }
    })
});
```

// 2nd Method

```
function foo(subject,body) {
    app.post('https://somenew.com/v1/',function(req,res){


    });
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Your `foo` function doesn't even have any parameters specified.

Comment: I have edited the question. I need to know how to call the method foo(subject,body) that will in return call another web service

Comment: what is the problem you are facing, what is wrong with the existing code?

Comment: do you want to send response only when second method is finished execution?

Comment: No not needed. After the first method is executed I need to call the 2nd method. But, the 2nd method accepts a few parameters as shown in the body of the post. Also, the header `Content-Type` should be set as well. Sorry, I am a beginner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) module

```js
var request = require('request');
request.post({
  url: 'https://somenew.com/v1/',
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
  },
  json: {
    "name": "My name is alex",
    "gender": ["All"],
    "Subject": "french",
    "Body": "men",
    "arrayOfLikes": {
      "sf": "tennis"
    }

  }
}, function(error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body) // your response body 
  }
})
```

the mistake you have made use express instance **app** to make call to external url that is not possible use above module to do so.

Comment: I also need to pass the following `name `, `gender`etc, in the body. How can i get this done ?

Comment: check the module out i have included the link to it

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was stuck with this for a long time.

Comment: `request` has been deprecated, try `axios`.